# Событийная модель C++

Tags: c++, события

Существуют ли какие либо подходы для создания событийной модели в C++ по аналогии с событиями из C#? Знаю что данный вопрос уже не раз поднимался, кто то свои делегаты пишет а на основе их уже события строит, кто как выходит из положения, но хотелось бы узнать как правильнее и лучше всего решать данный вопрос, что бы в будущем код работал стабильно и не пришлось переписывать.

Мне нужно создать проект на C++ (очень мало с ним работал) и я хотел бы его сделать на событиях (по логики задачи лучше всего подходит). От сюда и вопросы:
 1. Как в C++ принято создавать события (подписка / отписка и прочие)
 2. Возможно существует какие либо библиотеки где события уже реализованы?
 3. Если событийная модель не подходит то какие аналоги используют чаще всего ?

Я изначально думал сделать события на основе std::function - однако столкнулся с тем что нельзя однозначно определить какой именно объект / функция - были подписаны. Буду благодарен за советы и помощь.

Comment: Зачем вам вообще знать кто подписан? У событийной модели в том то и прелесть, клас, на который подписуются, от этого абстагируется. На него может хоть Санта Клаус подписаться. Ему главное вызвать определённый метод у всех подписчиков, а те пусть сами разбираются что дальше делать.

Comment: Boost.Signals .

Comment: @ДмитрийЗиненко Для осуществления отписки. Т.е. для того что бы а) - не дублировалась подписка б) перегрузить оператор -=.

Comment: @VTT а еще какие нибудь есть варианты ? с boost не работал не разу, но наслышен про него.

Comment: В С++  нет встроенного механизма обработки событий.   Но  можно пользоваться приложением(например QT)   и  Boost.Signals

Comment: QT не хочу, Boost - принято, что еще ?

Answer (score -2):

В качестве одного из вариантов, можно через наследование. Делаешь интерфейс (например полностью абстрактный класс) , класс, который подписуется, наследуется от него, класс на который подписываются хранит коллекци указателей на этот интерфейс. Подписаться/отписаться - добавить/удалить указатель из коллекции. Событие - для всех элементов из коллекции вызвать определённый метод. Только нужно быть осторожным, чтобы не разрушить подписчика не отписавшись и с операторами копирования/присваивания/перемещения.

Comment: не красиво, и слишком много нюансов + код раздуется ненужными методами... В общем не подходит.